# Could supersonic transport make a comeback?

Tags: airliner, supersonic

When the [Concorde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concorde) was retired from service, reasons given included:

- It was expensive to operate; it burned a lot of fuel and had high maintenance costs, resulting in high ticket prices
- Could only operate on overseas routes where the sonic boom it created could go essentially unnoticed
- It had a very limited market because of the above

But the Concorde was built with 1960s technology and aeronautical science. Modern aero engines are more fuel efficient, modern materials and manufacturing methods could potentially reduce maintenance costs, and there is today about 50 years of additional aeronautical science available.

So my question is this:

Is it possible to design a 200-300 seat airliner having performance comparable to Concorde (Mach 2+ at 50,000 ft or so), without creating a noticeable or objectionable sonic boom at ground level, and operating economics at least close to that of a typical subsonic airliner?

I have read similar questions ([[one]](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/3782/1467) and [[two]](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/29204/1467)) which explore the reasons Concorde was retired, but the discussions are framed around Concorde itself - an aircraft developed in the 1960s and never updated, or the abandoned [Boeing 2707](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_2707). None appear to acknowledge that at least four decades of scientific and technological progress has occurred since these aircraft were in development, and how that may or may not alter the feasibility of an SST service flying an all-new design. They also don't address the question of  whether new advances allow for large aircraft to fly supersonic without creating a noticeable or objectionable ground-level sonic boom.

Comment: related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/3782/1467

Comment: also related and possibly duplicate: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/29204/1467

Comment: The question is how much more money people are willing to pay for increased speed. Take railway for example, Beijing-Shanghai is around 800 miles where for equivalent of 75USD you have the choice of 4.5 hour on a coach seat on a high speed train or 14 hours for a sleeping car on a regular express train. Most people pick comfort over time efficiency. Even worse, right now IMO time sensitive business travel is already replaced by information technology.

Comment: Basically yes, sure, why not?

Comment: While the other questions mention the Concorde, personally I don't see how the answers would not apply to any other project in the same category, since they are general answers that do not deal with any specific project or airframe.

Comment: @Federico As opposed to the questions you've mentioned, this one is about the future. Considering the possibility of a change in demand, advances in available technology, and changes on the cost side, how can this question already have an answer. So why was it closed?

Comment: @user3528438: Another reason is diminishing returns.  If you look at total journey time, a large fraction is spent in not flying (especially not at cruising speed), but on TSA security theater, boarding, taxiing & waiting for takeoff, holding in landing patterns, deplaning & waiting for luggage...  Flying at supersonic speed doesn't really gain much for an airline passenger, though of course a supersonic bizjet could bypass much of it.

Comment: @jjack if we have to speak about the future, then it risks becoming opinion based, because we cannot forecast what will happen.

Comment: @Federico People knowing about a certain technology should be able to take careful guesses at what the future might look like.

Comment: @jjack that's opinion, and the SE network considers that as off-topic.

Comment: @Federico Well, there are well-founded opinions and unfounded opinions. And a lot of stuff that is already posted is strongly opinion-based. Judging a post as opinion-based might not even result in a high hit rate, if you look at it from a statistical test perspective.